# How to create Array from a String with preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I have string like bellow

```
Ref ID =={1234} [201] (text message)
```

I want to create an array like bellow

```
array(
    0 => 1234,
    1 => 201,
    2 => "text message"
)
```

Right now i am doing with Exploding the string method, but its took 8 lines of coding with multiple explode like bellow.

```
$data = array();
$str = 'Ref ID =={1234} [201] (text message)';
$bsArr1 = explode('}', $str);

$refIdArr = explode('{', $bsArr1);
$data[0] = $refIdArr[1];

$bsArr2 = explode(']', $bsArr[1]);
$codeArr = explode('[', $bsArr2[0]);
....
....
....
```

Is there anyway to achieve this with preg_match?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @revo i have achieved it with multiple explodes, but don't know is it possible to achieve it with preg_match.

Comment: As long as it's text processing it's possible with regular expressions. But the community expects to see your attempts on what you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple pregmatch:

```
preg_match('/{(\d+)}.*\[(\d+)].*\(([a-zA-Z ]+)\)/', 'Ref ID =={1234} [201] (text message)', $matches);

$arr[] = $matches[1];
$arr[] = $matches[2];
$arr[] = $matches[3];

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($arr);
die();
```

Comment: Thats a very hardcoded version of a preg_match... https://3v4l.org/Ki9kO

Comment: @Edgar thanks for your code.

Answer (score 2):

This will find one of `[{(` and capture all following lazy to `}])`

```
$str = "Ref ID =={1234} [201] (text message)";

preg_match_all("/[{|\[|\(](.*?)[\]|\)\}]/", $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "{1234}"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "[201]"
    [2]=>
    string(14) "(text message)"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "1234"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "201"
    [2]=>
    string(12) "text message"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/qKlSK